# Is it okay to do a service that query Azure Cosmos DB every minute?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am planning to make a reminder feature for a chatbot. The bot will ask the user and a reminder subject and DateTime will be saved to Cosmos DB.

What I am thinking is making that service will query/check the database every minute to see if a DateTime matches the current DateTime and then send a proactive chat to the user if it matches.
(I am thinking of azure function for this? or an infinite loop inside C#?)

My question is, will the payment for Azure Cosmos DB shoot up if I am to make a service that queries from Cosmos DB every minute? Is it wise to do this? Is there a better/alternate method to make a reminder feature for a chatbot?

Comment: I don't quite understand, is there a reason it has to check against the database? A check on the client side after x amount of time from last response should be enough and from that trigger what ever you want to happen..

Comment: Why don't you just retrieve the reminders, store them, and check every minute if one is reached ? That would be only 1 request per client with approximately the same logic

Comment: I would recommend getting all the reminders for a given time and using a different method (that won't cost as much) to poll for delivery time. One thing you can try is to use Azure Storage Queues with delayed delivery and when something shows up, you can send your proactive message. That limits your request count which in a month can really cost you if it's 1 request per minute per client/user of your app.

Comment: @Threezool if the user wants to be reminded after 30 days i think client side code can't handle it. and if ever the bot is restarted that reminder will be gone.

Comment: @Apolo but what is the interval to retrieve reminders and store them somewhere? if you retrieve the reminders and the user add a new reminder that additional reminder will not be with the ones you retreived?

Comment: @user10860402 add any new reminder to the existing list of reminders. You only need to fetch one to initialize client

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question "will the payment for Azure Cosmos DB shoot up if I am to make a service that queries from Cosmos DB every minute?"

Once you’ve fed your Cosmos DB container with some relevant data — that could be test data to start with — you can use the query explorer that’s available from the Azure portal. Besides helping you build and debug your SQL queries, this tool also reports the real cost of those queries.

So yes , it will  increase the consumption so is billing.

Here is something which you can use :

- Store all your reminders in database.
- If it's not too many which i am guessing ,won't be the case, store in some kind of cache or in-memory.
- Start the timer and keep tracking ticks, give a alert for any upcoming event , and you can manage the state too for the same object or you can send a event in queue. Update the event status after getting notification from queue.

In this way , cost would be optimized.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi i had been thinking of putting it in an in-memory storage but the bot is still new and i need to publish every now and then. but everytime i publish the in memory storage will be wiped